# react-admin useGetList filter doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks, filtering, react-admin

What I am trying to do is to find buildings that use the same calculation data as the one being edited. This is the code that doesn't work (total is 0 even though I know that there is a record that satisfies the filter):

```
      const record = useRecordContext<CalculationData>();
      const recordid = record.id;
      const { data, total } = useGetList('building', {
        filter: { calculationData: recordid },
        sort: { field: 'updated_at', order: 'DESC' },
      });
```

However when I do this:

```
      const record = useRecordContext<CalculationData>();
      const recordid = record.id;
      const { data, total } = useGetList('building', {
        filter: { city: 'Berlin' },
        sort: { field: 'updated_at', order: 'DESC' },
      });
      console.log(data[0].calculationData === recordid );
```

The output in the console is true.

Payload of the calculationData filter:

```
filter: {"where":{"calculationData":"6373b67dd9c67300634d54cb"},"skip":0,"limit":25,"order":["updated_at DESC"]}
```

Payload of the city filter:

```
filter: {"where":{"city":"Berlin"},"skip":0,"limit":25,"order":["updated_at DESC"]}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check what your data provider returns to getList. It must return {data: RaRecord[], total: number}

Comment: @OktayYuzcan that's right, it returns data and total. The thing I'm confused with is why it works for the city but not for another string property

Comment: The problem likely lies in your dataProvider or in your API, as the getList query seems to send the right parameters.